# Cómo puedo validar este formulario?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Deseo validar un formulario HTML. El formulario se conecta con un JSP para hacer la transacción en el servidor. He intentando con JS o Jquery, sin éxito. Espero puedan ayudarme. He intentado de muchas formas y buscado mucha información pero no he logrado hacer todas las validaciones.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
    <h1>REGISTRAR PRODUCTO</h1>
    <form action="grabarProducto.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="op" value="3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>CODIGO</td><td><input class="form-control" name="txtid" placeholder="Inserte el codigo del producto..." id="txtid"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PRODUCTO</td><td><input class="form-control" name="txtprod" placeholder="Ingrese el producto..."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PRECIO x UNIDAD</td><td><input class="form-control" name="txtprecio" placeholder="Precio Unitario..." id="txtprecio"></td>
            <td id="errorPrecio">

            </td>
        </tr>introducir el código aquí`introducir el código aquí`
        <tr>
            <td>STOCK</td><td><input class="form-control" name="txtstock" placeholder="Stock..."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ESTADO</td><td><input class="form-control" name="txtest" placeholder="Estado..." ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Grabar"></td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
            </div>

        </div> 

    </form>
        <a href="listarProductos.jsp" class="btn btn-info" role="button" id="btnEnviar">Pagina Principal</a>

</center>

    </body>
</html>
```

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el formulario coloque en el form **onsubmit="return validarForm();"** y una funcion en el javasript para que se ejecute el codigo.

en la parte de estado esta mal definida, se deber utilizar los select ya que el usuario no va a entender bien esta parte

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<form action="grabarProducto.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return validarForm();"  >
        <input type="hidden" name="op" value="3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>CODIGO</td><td><input class="form-control" name="txtid" placeholder="Inserte el codigo del producto..." id="txtid"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PRODUCTO</td><td><input class="form-control" name="txtprod" placeholder="Ingrese el producto..."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PRECIO x UNIDAD</td><td><input class="form-control" name="txtprecio" placeholder="Precio Unitario..." id="txtprecio"></td>
            <td id="errorPrecio">

            </td>
        </tr>introducir el código aquí`introducir el código aquí`
        <tr>
            <td>STOCK</td><td><input class="form-control" name="txtstock" placeholder="Stock..."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ESTADO</td><td>
<input class="form-control" name="txtest" placeholder="Estado..." >
<select name="txtestado">
  <option value=""></option> 
  <option value="0" selected>Activo</option>
  <option value="1">Inactivo</option>
</select>


</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Grabar"></td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
            </div>

        </div> 
    </form>

<script>
function validarForm(){
    var txtprecio= $("#txtprecio").val();
    if(txtprecio==10){
      alert("true");
      return true;
      
    }else{
    alert("false");
      return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: No importa si el form tiene un action que ejecuta un JSP? Igual lo validará?

Comment: Probandolo me sirvió muchísimo amigo. Marcar como respuesta que ayudó

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste agregándole una atributo "required" a los inputs?
Ejm:

```
<input class="form-control" name="txtstock" placeholder="Stock..." required>
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que son validaciones personalizadas. Por ejemplo, para el precio, debe estar entre 10 y 50, para el estado solo debe admitir 0 y 1.